# Update mysql db password field security

Tags: php, mysql

I have a user database with sha256 hashed password fields.
Now I wish to update this with [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) to add the flavour of salt.

How would I do this the right way?
I believe I have to update the field when the user does the next login, right?
How would I check if this has already been done for the specific user?

Right now I check if the field contains '$P$', but it doesn't look right to me.

Thx in advance

Comment: How are the SHA256 passwords encoded? Just as hex (ie `$` is an invalid character) or some other encoding?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure :/
I'm not very experienced in this. Just starting to find my way around it

Comment: Ok, better go with either of the two below suggestions then, if `$` could show up in your existing data, using `$P$` could be bad.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I thought. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go for a similar approach but with a twist. Create a column (TINYINT) default 0. When the user updates their password, set it to 1.

Less extra data in the database then another column.

Comment: Thank you guys. I'll use a new column for this. Would I empty the old password field after creating the new one?

Comment: if you are using 2 password columns, you can empty old password once new one is set. If you are using a column flag(As suggested in this answer) then you will be updating the password column to use the new password, you wont need to empty anything then.

Comment: It all comes down to if you want to save the old version of the password or not. If not, then just use a flag, if you want to save it, use two columns.

Comment: Works like a charm.
I decided to delete the old password. Keeping it there after upgrading database security by using a better hashing, seemed wrong to me.

Thx again

Answer (score 3):

well, there can be many ways, what i would do is, Create another column to store new passwords. While logging user in, check if new password is null, if yes, log them in based on old password column and old logic, and then update new password from the raw password you received from user. This way you can eventually port almost all users to new Passwords.